# Python:Minumim Function

Tags: python, min

I'm new to Python and I have a problem which needs to be solved with the min function in Python.

I have three ingredients which are:

```
chicken = 20
lettuce = 30
tomato = 50
max_burgers = "Code Goes Here"
```

You need to make burgers with these. Each burger contains 1 piece of chicken, 3 lettuce leaves and 6 tomato slices. Using the min function, I need to calculate the maximum number of burgers which can be made with these ingredients. I've already done this with a while loop and the answer is 8. But I can not do so with a min function.

Any sort of help would be greatly appreciated.

Than You.

Comment: Where's the code you tried, not just the initial values?

Comment: How many burgers will lettuce make? Use integer division - `30//3`. Once you have 3 numbers in a list, you can use `min` on the list.  Give it a try and post your code back in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The `min` function takes an arbitrary amount of arguments and takes the lowest value:

```
>>> min(1, 2, 3,)
1
```

To solve this, simply calculate the max amount of burgers that could be made with each ingredient using floor division, and then pick the lowest amount:

```
>>> chicken, lettuce, tomato = 20, 30, 50
>>> min(chicken, lettuce // 3, tomato // 6)
8
```